# Fatal error while i build my activex control

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, activex, atl

I have created an activex control using mfc and added the control to a dialog application. It compiled fine but when i modify the activex control code and build it, i am getting an error message "fatal error LNK1168: cannot open C:\te\Debug\te.ocx for writing".

I removed the activex control from the app and used regsvr32 -u to unregister it but still it fails. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer this [Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308358) to resolve this issue.